# file size of react-native project

Tags: react-native

After creating a new react-native project using **init**, and I checked the project folder size which is above 450MB. Is this a normal one or am I missing something.

[image]

Step I follow to create project: **react-native init appname**

React Native Version           : **0.63.2**

So, please explain me what's going wrong? Suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, react use a lot of modules, native code etc

The final apk will weigh like 50mo but if you wan't less, you can do an apk bundle, a set of apks for each processors.